# start nodejs app with certain settings?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there a way to make an app with nodejs that can be started with additional parameters?
A few examples:

```
node myApp.js -nolog
```

would start the app with the custom `noLog=true` parameter, so that things would not be console.logged..

```
node myApp.js -prod
```

would start the app in a specific set of production settings.

I am not sure if there is anything equivalent in node already.. If this is a duplicate, possibly because I was not even aware of the keyword to search this specific problem's answers.

Enlighten me!

Comment: try https://github.com/substack/node-optimist to parse argv, and use `require` to load different settings.

Comment: @ChiChou seems to be deprecated, but it's a good direction! thanks!

Comment: checkout Yargs the successor of optimist! https://github.com/chevex/yargs

Comment: I just checked optimist itself, why are the other things required when there is minimist? @MohammadRahchamani

Comment: @Zettam sorry I paste a wrong repo. Use this one insead https://www.npmjs.org/package/minimist

Comment: @ChiChou it worked great, post it as an answer so that I can pick that as the answer :) thanks.

Comment: @Zettam in the optimist page they said "See yargs for the modern, pirate-themed successor to optimist." and in the yargs page : "args is now the official successor to optimist. ..." if you want to use your project in long-term it's better to use yargs because it's supporting and it will update to fix bugs , etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read command line arguments you need to parse `process.argv`, or use a 3rd-party module like    [minimist](https://www.npmjs.org/package/minimist):

```
var argv = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2));

// do something ...
var config = argv.config;
if (config === 'dev') {
    // set the flag
}
```

Then start your app via `node app.js --config=dev`.

In most general case you need to include more than one option, and manually hardcoding them in code is a bad idea. A recommended way is to write them down in a configutaion file, then use `require` to parse. You can use both `.js` and `.json` to store configutation, but `.js` is more convenient because JSON format is too strict, especially it does not even allow you put comments.

So here's a solution. Organize you configurations as follow:

```
config
  ├── dev.js
  ├── production.js
```

`production.js` is defined as a "base class", which stores all required settings, and exposes them using `module.export`.

```
module.exports = {
    db: {
        backend: 'mysql',
        user: 'username',
        password: 's3cr3t'
        // ...
    }
};
```

`dev.js` inherits all properties from production, override the value to fit your local env. It's recommend to ignore this file in version control system (git, SVN, etc.), so your local configutaion will not conflict with others in the project. To deep copy and merge an object, [node.extend](https://github.com/dreamerslab/node.extend) may help.

```
var base = require('./production'),
    extend = require('node.extend');

var overrides = {
    db: {
         user: 'root',
         password: ''
    }
};

module.exports = extend(overrides, base);
```